# tufte-book with endnotes

Tags: formatting, tufte, endnotes

Formatting the following code shows that endnotes in the tufte-book class have a wider text width than the main body of a document. I would like to avoid this.

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] place end note here.\endnote{\lipsum[1]}
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Comment: It gets better if you use real text in a language that can be hyphenated, instead of Lorem ipsum. I see no big deal with a real-world piece of text.

Comment: I noticed the problem when formatting an actual document.

Comment: I see what you art talking about. The problem does go away when using real text. I used the tufte-book class in my original document. The problem persists when I use that class. This class formats footnotes in the margin. In my document, the main text of an endnote clashes with footnotes it may contain.

Comment: To get hyphenation of lorem ipsum text just load `\usepackage[main=latin]{babel}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `endnote`s package sets the endnotes with `\rightskip=0pt`, which gives no room for flexibility at the end of the line.  If you add the draft option to the class you will see a black box at the end of nearly every line in the in end notes, indicating the lines are overfull.  We can correct this by changing `\enoteformat` which is originally

```
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip\z@ \leftskip\z@ \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
```

and use the `\rightskip` amount of the `tufte` ragged right:

```
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=\RaggedRightRightskip\leftskip=0pt \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
```

To get best results enable hyphenation patterns for the language used:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage[main=latin]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=\RaggedRightRightskip\leftskip=0pt \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] place end note here.\endnote{\lipsum[1]}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Without this adjustment and with the `draft` option provided the output is

[image: Sample output]

By default `\RaggedRightRightskip` is `0pt plus 0.08\hsize`.  You might want a smaller value in the endnotes where the font size is reduced.  One choice would be

```
\rightskip=0pt plus 0.04\hsize
```

giving

[image: Extra sample]

```
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt plus 0.04\hsize\leftskip=0pt \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
```

Comment: No microtype package?

Comment: @KeksDose The tufte class already loads `microtype`.